# trying to configure webpack plugin and it fails with this error

Tags: webpack

trying to run webpack -p I am on windows 7 64 bit, fails with attached error 
not sure where I am going wrong 
     here is my webpackconfig.js file

```
 var HtmlWebpack=require('html-webpack-plugin');
 var HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin ({
  template: __dirname + 'app/index.html',
   filename: 'index.html',
   inject: 'body'
   });
 module.exports={
  entry:[
    './app/index.js'
 ],
  output:{
     path: __dirname + '/dist',
     filename: "index_bundle.js"
    },

  module: {
    loaders:[
    {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"}

    ]
  },
    plugins:[HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
 }
```

[image: error message I get]

Comment: Change first line to `var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');`

Comment: Thanks that got it for me..you the man!

Answer (score 2):

The HtmlWebpackPlugin is a reference not found because when you've created you used a different name: HtmlWebpack

If you change the line:

```
 var HtmlWebpack=require('html-webpack-plugin');
```

to

```
 var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
```

It should work.